# How to upgrade ubuntu server 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: server, upgrade, 10.04

I have to upgrade Ubuntu server 10.04 to 12.04.

10.04 is not supported any more. So what step I have to do, for a clean upgrade?

I did the following steps:

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-r‌​eleases.ubuntu.com/g‌​' /etc/apt/sources.list 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

After some time, the upgrade is aborting: ...Restoring original system state

```
root@vupapzimbra01:~# sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
update-manager-core is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-2.6.32-41-server linux-headers-2.6.32-41
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@vupapzimbra01:~#


root@vupapzimbra01:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Release:        10.04
Codename:       lucid

Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en [2395 B]
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en [3341 kB]
Fetched 19.9 MB in 6s (1873 kB/s)

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done

Calculating the changes

Calculating the changes

Error authenticating some packages

It was not possible to authenticate some packages. This may be a
transient network problem. You may want to try again later. See below
for a list of unauthenticated packages.

accountsservice
apparmor
.
.
wpasupplicant
xkb-data


Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done

=== Command detached from window (Thu May  4 09:20:53 2017) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Thu May  4 09:20:53 2017) ===
```

Comment: why do you want to upgrade to 12.04 instead of 16.04 for example?

Comment: Its also possible to upgrade to 16.04. But my problem is the upgrade from 10.04. I get no patches....
thanks

Comment: @Yaron It is the preferred way to upgrade to the nearest LTS and then possibly again.

Comment: I did the following steps now:

Comment: sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade

After some time, the upgrade is aborting:
...Restoring original system state
thanks for your help
Hannes

Comment: Did you execute `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade` ?

Comment: @Melebius I have updated the question!

Comment: In your question (and in answers), *if you indent four spaces*, the line is rendered as `code` , and it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

its better to download iso and re install 
you could install 12.04 Ubuntu server
Click [link](https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu-iso/12.04/)
32 bit or 64 bit you could select
the upgrade is not possible for old versions
or try 17.04 Click [torrent link](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-17.04-server-i386.iso.torrent?_ga=2.106099140.671162159.1493886332-494091449.1493647815)

Comment: Hi,I tried to connect the 12.04 Iso to the VM Ware and restartet the server.
I just had the option to install Ubunto 12.04, but I didn have to option to upgrade to OS....
thanks

Comment: its not easy to upgrade to old version you could only reinstall if you want

Comment: what do you mean with reinstall?
I want to upgrade den ubuntu 10.04 server to an actual release...

Comment: it is not possible i mean to install 10.04 server you cant upgrade