# Links fail when using apt-get to try and install update-manager

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

I have a leased server I've had for five years that is running Ubuntu 10.0.04LTS. I was trying to do an upgrade to something more recent (since apt-get kept erroring out) and found I don't have update-manager installed. apt-get can't find what it needs to install update-manager, so I'm stuck now. Ultimately, I just want to upgrade the system. So the question is how do I install update-manager when apt-get isn't making it happen?

Important point: I don't have any GUI here, only the command line.

Comment: "apt-get can find what it needs", is this right or is the other way round?

Comment: Ubuntu LTS versions have a five year life span; so it should have been upgraded ages back.  The mirror I use drop their files a few months after a release is EOL hence errors can be expected post EOL depending on what's in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Find a server that has the files, point there or `wget` what you want & `dpkg` install, or follow 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/911691/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-server-10-04-to-12-04

Comment: @George, yep 'can't', edited.

Comment: @chris, probably 5 years and 9 months to be more exact.

Comment: @chrisguiver, thanks, the question that linked to gave me the answer I needed https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/23576.